# Redirect | HTACCESS | Delete language indicator

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, joomla

I want to redirect in the file .htaccess this:

```
www.site.com/XX/page/page/

to

www.site.com/page/page
```

Is that possible to do to every single page that contains "XX"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/XX/(.+)$ /$1
```